# Call python file from another file with arguments containing spaces

Tags: python, subprocess

If I run a script, which runs and passing arguments to another script

```
python = 'C:/Python27/' 
route = 'D:/core.py'
arguments = '{'a': 'apple'}'
subprocess.call('{0} {1} {2}'.format(python, route, arguments))
```

In core.py I get only `'{'a':` as an argument, everything after space is lost. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Put the argument in quotes, just as you would from the command line.

Comment: What is arguments supposed to be? I get a syntax error on that line.

Comment: Did you consider using a function of the other script by importing it as a module instead of calling it as subprocess?

Comment: Sorry, that was an abstract example and I mess up my strings. Should be `'{0} "{1}"'.format(x, y)` and I did `'{0} {1}'.format(x, y)`, so it does not work.

Comment: Are you using `shell=True`? A default `subprocess.call('some arbitrary string')` will attempt to find and execute something called `some arbitrary string`, spaces and all.

Comment: No, I am not using `shell = True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line 
    arguments = '{'a': 'apple'}' 
to
    arguments = "{'a': 'apple'}"